# Removing tags from question titles makes 'Questions with similar titles' useless

Tags: discussion, tags, title

I have had a number of titles to my questions on SO edited to remove text such as `MySQL:`  with no explanation or notification.

I'm guessing that this is because someone thinks it's redundant since the question also has the same tag.

However, prefixes such as these help the system list relevant questions in both the '*Questions with similar titles*' and '*Similar Questions*' boxes.

Note that I have seen some questions related to this, but none that give **concrete reasons** for the current trend of removing tags from titles.

Comment: So why can't you write the tag into the title organically without cramming it in as the first word?

Comment: I am unconvinced. I feel like putting "MySQL: " in the title will only help the system find other posts with "MySQL: " in the title, and that if you really have a well-written post/title the system won't have to resort to "title tags." I have no data to back this up, though; do you have data to support your position?

Comment: The explanation is "don't put tags in the title, its redundant and pointless."  And how do you come by the claim "prefixes such as these help the system list relevant questions"?  Which of the dev team for SE tell you this?

Comment: My question was *REPLACE statement with embedded IF() logic?*, how do I "organically" include 'MySQL' in there?

Comment: *"REPLACE statement with embedded IF() logic in MySQL"*. But if you tag it with the `mysql` tag, you don't have to write it into the question title at all. BTW downvotes on Meta just indicate disagreement with your question's premise; they're not an indictment of the question itself.

Comment: Don't take the downvotes personally; they don't express any opinion on you (the poster). Specifically on meta sites, downvotes express only disagreement with the position/arguments you've made/taken. (I once [asked a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-rename-excel-vba-and-others-to-excel-automation-excel-active) with 24 downvotes.)

Comment: Hiya! I understand that you may want the question to read the way you have it but the edit is far superior. Continuing to rollback to the rude version will lead to the question being locked.

Comment: I created a feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337935/suggestiong-show-tags-in-similar-questions

Comment: @Catija how can I disassociate myself from this question? It no longer represents me.

Answer (score 9):

It's a matter of standardization.

Your method doesn't work for the same reason that allowing punctuation in telephone numbers in the text field of a database doesn't work.  Some people will use dashes to separate the numbers, others will use periods.  Some people will use parentheses, others won't.

In addition, allowing tags at the beginning of question titles allows all sorts of bad tags like:

```
[Solved]
[Homework]
[Newbie]
```

to creep into the system.

Rather than catering to all of these different ideas, we cater to none, and instead implemented a tagging system that standardizes the categorization process, making it work the same way for everyone.

Comment: +1, tags go with tags.