# "Questions with Similar Titles" Could Do Better

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, similar-questions

I'm all for removing tags from titles. However, the underlying point of "[Question Titles - Removing Tags makes 'Questions with similar titles' useless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95089/question-titles-removing-tags-makes-questions-with-similar-titles-useless)" is valid. We need a better way to display actual similar questions.

I just realized this when preparing to ask about how to find out what changed from one build to another in TFS 2010 when using branching. Of course, being the "tag-remover" that I am, I planned to use the [tfs](/questions/tagged/tfs) and [tfs2010](/questions/tagged/tfs2010) tags. The title "How to Determine the Work Items Fixed in a Build?" displayed a similar question list with only three TFS-related questions. Saying "TFS Build" helped a lot, even though many of the questions didn't have "Build" in the title. Adding "Branch" didn't seem to change much.

I have to admit that even using the search box doesn't give a much better set of questions (searching for "[find out what changed from one build to another in TFS 2010 when using branching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=find+out+what+changed+from+one+build+to+another+in+TFS+2010+when+using+branching)" returns 5000+ questions). Still, maybe if we moved the tags list to before the title, we could narrow the "similar questions" list to those which are similar within the tags. This might also reduce the need people feel to put the tags *into* the question titles.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Adding tags before title of the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52750/162705)?

Answer (score -1):

This request doesn't really make sense; "Questions with Similar Titles" does exactly what it says it does.

What you want is already covered by

[Feedback requested: Similar Questions displayed in sidebar on /ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91568/feedback-requested-similar-questions-displayed-in-sidebar-on-ask)

Which is fed by body, title and tags. However the body must be a minimum number of characters for this to begin working.

Comment: The "Similar Questions" are great, but I still don't understand why you require the minimum body length. If I start with just title and tags, the "Similar Questions" sidebar could already show me that I'm about to compose a duplicate question.