# Show tags in "Similar questions"

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, duplicate-questions

Actual situation

- When searching on stackexchange you get a list of search results. Each topic also contains a list of its tags below it.
- When adding a new question, after typing the title, a field "similar questions" will show up with possible related questions. However, that list does not contain tag.  Therefore, when your question is about "C++ bla" you might get search results for "C# bla". But you don't know, that it's for C# unless you open the question and check the tags.

Suggestion:

- Add the list of tags also to the results within "similar questions".

Misc:

- This will prevent threads like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95089/question-titles-removing-tags-makes-questions-with-similar-titles-useless)